# Inserting current user id into another table PHP

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys

I am fairly new to PHP and am not sure how to do this.

I have two tables:

> owner (ownerid(PK), username, password)
>
> venue (venueid(PK), owenerid(FK), venuename, location, number)

owner stores the details of the current logged in user. Once the user is logged in they enter details into a form that gets inserted into venue table.

How do I take the `ownerid` of the current logged in user and insert it into `ownerid (in venue table)` so that at a later stage I can select all venues that a particular user has added, and only that logged in user can view them.

I am pretty new to PHP so would appreciate as much explanation / code as possible :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a logged in user you will be able to identify them either through a cookie or a session. If you store their `ownerid` in the session variable, then you will be able to access it whenever you require

```
$ownerid = $_SESSION['user']
```

You can then use that variable in association with the selected venues, and relate them together so only this user can view them when logged in, matching their ownerid

Comment: Sorry I am so new to this and would love a bit more explanation!  When do I do that?  Once they are logged in or when they are creating an account?  Thank you

Comment: I assumed you wanted this for when visitors are logged in? If so when the login you verify their username and password. If they are correct you then redirect them to your members page, and set a session. When you set the session give it the value of the member's id, that way you can look up any venues associated to that ID. If you are not yet familiar with sessions, then I suggest you research them first.